# Get entry with max value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a MySQL database with lots of entris of highscores for a game. I would like to get the "personal best" entry with the max value of score.

I found a solution that I thought worked, until I got more names in my database, then it returnes completely different results.

My code so far:

```
SELECT name, score, date, version, mode, custom
FROM highscore
WHERE score = 
    (SELECT MAX(score) 
             FROM highscore 
             WHERE name = 'jonte' && gamename = 'game1')
```

For a lot of values, this actually returns the correct value as such:

```
JONTE   240 2014-04-28 02:52:33 1   0   2053
```

It worked fine with a few hundred entries, some with different names. But when I added new entries and swapped name to 'gabbes', for the new names I instead get a list of multiple entries. I don't see the logic here as the entries in the database seem quite identical with some differences in data.

```
JONTE   176 2014-04-28 11:03:46 1   0   63  
GABBES  176 2014-04-28 11:09:12 1   0   3087
```

The above has two entires, but sometimes it may also return 10-20 entries in a row too.

Any help?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Well, your table can have more than one entry which has a score equal to the maximum. What is your desired output for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the high score for each person (i.e. personal best) you can do this...

```
SELECT name, max(score)
FROM highscore
WHERE gamename = 'game1'
GROUP BY name
```

Alternatively, you can do this...

```
SELECT name, score, date, version, mode, custom
FROM highscore h1
WHERE score = 
    (SELECT MAX(score) 
             FROM highscore h2
             WHERE name = h1.name && gamename = 'game1')
```

**NOTE:** In your SQL, your subclause is missing the `name = h1.name` predicate.

Note however, that this second option will give multiple rows for the same person if they recorded the same high score multiple times.

Comment: The first solution what was I did early on, it works for just top score per name, but not if I want other fields of that entry. (ie. The custom value for example is not the one connected to that score)
Your second solution seems to do exactly what I'm looking for tho, so thanks a lot for that!

Comment: Any reason why a request like this would be unusually slow? Ever since I made these changes the request can take between seconds.. my other requests go through quickly tho. Running this in phpMyAdmin can take up to a minute while others go at 0.0002 seconds.. the database has a few thousand entries.

Comment: Shouldn't take long at all. Have you got an index on the name column? Try that first. If still slow, add an index to the score column. I would expect the query to take less than 1 second.

Comment: Added index to name (VARCHAR(100)) and score (DOUBLE) but still taking between 30-60 seconds. Could it be connected to score being a double? My exact query is here, based on your answer: http://pastebin.com/phi3ENyC

Comment: @jsmars so you have a non-unique index on score with only score as the field in the index AND you have another index, this one on name, with only name as the field in the index? If so, it should be lightning fast. I'll test now and get back to you with my findings.

Comment: @jsmars I created a table with 100,000 entries with the same column structure as yours. I create two indexes i1 and i2 on name and score (respectively). I ran the query and it ran in 0.82 sec. So, I think maybe you haven't indexed the fields?

Comment: @jsmars if you have done all that. Please let me know what other indexes you have defined on the table. It may be choosing a different one than the one you think. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive testing! My SQL skills are quite rusty so please excuse my incompetence. I have a unique index called ID, and after your suggestion I clicked "index" in phpMyAdmin on both name and score with positive result, here is a screenshot of SHOW INDEXES for the table and the structure. Maybe you can see a problem there, I see mutliple name entries for index which I'm not sure about. http://postimg.org/image/xqb165bhv/

Comment: You have a few indexes on the same fields. I would drop the following indexes "id", "name_2", "name_3".

Comment: You could also create a single composite index on "gamename" AND "name" (in that order). If so, you would replace the "use index (name)" in the subquery with the index name of the new composite query (or just remove the "use index" clause in the subquery).

Comment: Tried both these methods now, the use index doesn't really make any difference, the composite index brings the time down to 10-15 seconds.. alot better but still way too much. I'm wondering if there may be something wrong the the server settings / mysql setup on the server.. any way to print a list of settings which could help find such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The multiple entries are returned because multiple entries have the same high score. You can add `LIMIT 1` to get only a single entry. You can choose which entry to return with the `ORDER BY` clause.